# Azure application proxy application will not pass entered Active Directory credentials

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am able to access the login page for the application I have setup via application proxy, but when I enter my credentials, it indicates authentication failed.  This particular application uses active directory to authenticate and grant access to the application.  Logging into the application locally works as expected.  Is there something else that must be done with application proxy to pass the entered credentials back to AD?

Answer (score 0):

**Application Proxy Prerequisite:**

Before you get started with single sign-on for IWA applications, make sure your environment is ready with the following settings and configurations:

1. User principal name.
2. On-premises user principal name.
3. Username part of user principal name.
4. Username part of on-premises user principal name.
5. On-premises SAM account name

**Configure Active Directory:**

The Active Directory configuration varies, depending on whether your Application Proxy connector and the application server are in the same domain or not. please make sure you have followed those [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-with-kcd#configure-active-directory)

**Implementation Guide Line**

For right Implementation process please have look on [here](https://www.jgspiers.com/azure-application-proxy/#SSO-Options).

I am also referring some ***common trouble*** in [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-troubleshoot) please take a look.

**Escalation**

If you don't found your problem in trouble section below that would seen `My error wasn't listed here` like below

[image]

click on `feedback team` to get immediate help. at this email `aadapfeedback@microsoft.com`

Thank you very much and happy coding!

Comment: The environment is ready.  I had seen the above article but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Launenhaft Would you kindly notify the your feedback to the given link.